# Failed to load resources: the server responded a status 404 not found as react app deployed on ingress with subpath

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to deploy react application wants to deploy along with /subpath on ingress but while loading react app in browser it show blank screen resources are not found.

*Ingress.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: reactccfk
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: helmaudit
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  creationTimestamp: "2021-12-23T21:45:46Z"
  generation: 6
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: hello-kubernetes-ingress
  namespace: helmaudit
  resourceVersion: "255406763"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/helmaudit/ingresses/hello-kubernetes-ingress
  uid: ae7bdf30-7361-4ea7-963e-92e2604a3ff1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-kubernetes-reactccfk
          servicePort: 3000
        path: /hello
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Can you paste your ingress object here ?

Comment: @Supermacy is it mandatory to set /subpath in react app also?

Comment: @Supermacy Question edited with ingress yaml for your reference.

Comment: Could you also include your deployment manifest?

Comment: @Lucky Couple of quick questions ?
1. Does service name hello-kubernetes-reactccfk exists ?
2. Are you able to see any logs in kubernetes pods ?
3. Blank page is coming from react or from ingress ?

Comment: @Supermacy answers as below:
1. Yes
2. Yes
3. While opening url in browser it show blank page.

Comment: What are the logs @Lucky